# Python: Print floating point numbers with two digits after decimal

Tags: python

Write a program that asks the user for the price of an item, and then prints out a bill for the item. The bill includes the item price, the sales tax on the item, and the total amount paid by the customer.  The sales tax is 5% of the item price. The total bill is the price of the item plus the sales tax.

The bill, if the item cost $99, would look like this:

Price          $  99.00
Sales tax          4.95
Total          $ 103.95

This is what I have so far:

```
price = float(input("Price $"))
tax = .05
salestax = (price*tax)
total = ((price*tax)+ price)
print("Sales tax  ", salestax)
print("Total $", total)
```

Can someone help me with making the printed values have two decimal places?

Right now this is my output:

```
Price $99
Sales tax   4.95
Total $ 103.95
```

Clearly, the spacing is wrong, and not all of the dollar amounts have 2 decimal places

Comment: Convert it to string, split by `.`, and see if the second element exists. If so, count the digits and fill the remaining with `0`. If not, add `.00` to the end.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Comment: "%.2f" , this is what my professor uses, but I can't figure out how to add this into my code correctly.

Comment: `print("Sales tax %.2f" % tax)`

Comment: If your professor expects a certain formatting method, then make that known in your question statement. It sounds as-if your professor expects a printf-style output, and your question is mainly focused on how to print a decimal value with a scale (the number of digits right of the decimal) of two.

Comment: It would also be useful to know the version of Python being used or expected for your answer. Python 3 is the standard nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `print(f'{total:.2f})` to print the first 2 numbers after the float point. Or, if you want, you can change the quantity of numbers changing the ".2f"in the sentence.

Or, you can use the `round()` function. Try this: `round(total, 2)` The 2 number represents how many number will appear after the dot.

Comment: unfortunately, this isn't what my professor taught me so I cant use this, but thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're having the issue when a float is entered as price ($99.99).

You could use str(round(total, 2)) to round your numbers to the 2nd decimal place.

```
price = float(input("Price $"))
tax = .05
salestax = (price*tax)
total = ((price*tax)+ price)
print("Sales tax  $" + str(round(salestax, 2)))
print("Total $" + str(round(total, 2)))
```

outputs to:

```
Price $45
Sales tax  $2.25
Total $47.25
```

You may run into rounding errors where the sales tax will only list 1 decimal place like $5.0. But should work for most prices.

Comment: unfortunately, this isn't what my professor taught me so I cant use this, but thank you.

Comment: but yes I am running into the problem where the outputs arent spaced correctly

Comment: how would you make it so that the input is also 2 decimals?

Answer (score 0):

```
num = 3.1356548655458
rNum = round(num,2)
print(rNum)
```

result will be 3.14
''''round (the Number,How much digits you want after decimal)''''